# What is your best laydown

Tags: texas-hold-em

this question is inspired by this question: [What is the biggest WOW! moment you ever saw in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/what-is-the-biggest-wow-moment-you-ever-saw-in-poker) and is what are your personal best laydown stories? tell us about the best laydowns you ever made, that will generally be met with such comments as are you crazy, to lay that down.

Answer (score 0):

mine was in a 4/8 limit game at the Peppermil in Reno, full table of nine players dealt in. I was in early position one off from under the gun, I looked down to AK suited, under the gun raised. I raised again the next player behind me raised. one other player in late postion called, as did the other two already involved, the flop came KKQ, no suits to speak of, I bet out and was raised, and all players remaining stayed for the action, my take on things was that the player directly on my left had flopped, Queens full, but the player behind him is the one that left me confounded, so I went into the tank a bit to think it about what was going on here. after thinking on it for a minute or so, I concluded late guy with all his cold calling of of double and triple bets, was likely slow playing aces. So, I figured I was already beat by Queens full and was likely drawing dead to my kicker to make a full house. So I laid down my three kings with the ace kicker, it was a good lay down. the other really good laydown I once made was simply pocket queens preflop when a couple players started having a raising war with each other, in the obvious to me at the time, the players where likely holding large pocket pairs, or at least one was. Queens full won that pot, and my suspected guy with pocket aces showed, and I lost 4 dollars.rather then putting 8 more in to see the flop.

Comment: You weren't drawing dead even if you were right about the aces. Case king or any running pair.

Comment: drawing dead enough I thought at the time

Answer (score -1):

I did some pretty good laydowns over the years, this one was the first, so special memory. Home game, 9 players, blinds 1-2. 100 BB deep when we start (playing for more than 1 hour when the hand occurs). We all know each other, having played a few games over the last months. I'm UTG+1. I hold 9♣9♥ and raise PF. CO call, BB call. I'm known as a tight-aggressive player, villain as (quite/very) loose-aggressive, but excellent player too.

Flop comes 9♠7♥4♠

I bet ~60% of the pot, to get some information and start protecting against a possible (weak) draw. CO calls. BB folds.

Turn card is 3♠

I bet ~60% of the pot again, villain thinks for a moment and 3-bets. My analysis and guts tell me that he isn't bluffing. So I start narrowing down his range and potential hands. I think he might hold some suited connectors (or one-gap maybe). But not strong enough if he think I hold the A♠ and he probably thinks I wouldn't have bet so much on the river if I had the nut flush. In my opinion, he puts me on a top-3 pocket pair (AA / KK / QQ would totally be my range and style of play on this board), hoping that I put him on A9 or K9 and shove.

I finally fold face up. The whole table goes like "*wow!*". Villain asks me why I did this. I explain my thinking, before he congratulates me and shows:

> 5♥ 6♣ for a straight, exactly what I had told him. I had discarded 77 and 44 in my mind, even if they were in his PF range. But 5-6 was such him that I couldn't think of anything else. We agree to see the river, a brick that changes nothing...